Computing Lyapunov spectrum numerically in 2 dimensions: code yields exponents with positive sum?
I implemented a QR-decomposition based algorithm for estimating the Lyapunov spectrum for the following two-dimensional discrete map, described in Sprott (1993):
$x_{n+1}=a_0+a_1x_n+a_2x^2_n+a_3x_ny_n+a_4y_n+a_5y^2_n$
$y_{n+1}=a_6+a_7x_n+a_8x_n^2+a_9x_ny_n+a_{10}y_n+a_{11}y^2_n$
I got the algorithm from Nonlinear Dynamics by Datseris & Parlitz. It is essentially an orbit-separation method, where at every iteration of the map I replace the perturbation vectors by orthogonal vectors (the $Q$ in $QR$).
For a given choice of parameters $a_i$ and initial point $(x_0, x_1)$, if the resulting map admits Lyapunov exponents $\lambda_1>\lambda_2$, and $\lambda_1>0$, I assume the solution is chaotic.
However, it was my understanding that the sum $\lambda_1+\lambda_2$ should not be positive. Otherwise it makes no sense to define the Kaplan-Yorke dimension.
Through my testing, however, I've found a number of parameters that admit solutions where $\lambda_1>0$ and $\lambda_1+\lambda_2>0$.
You can see my code and the matplotlib plots on this Google Colab notebook. My implementation is in Python, but I also used the ChaosTools package in Julia by the authors of Nonlinear Dynamics to verify for a handful of sets of parameters that my Lyapunov spectrum calculations were correct.
Why is this? And given these results, how should I go about computing the Kaplan-Yorke dimension?
Moreover, the solutions for which $\lambda_1+\lambda_2>0$ visually appear "more chaotic" than the solutions for which $\lambda_1+\lambda_2\leq0$:
Solutions where the sum is positive

Solutions where the sum is negative

Qualitatively, these results seem independent of the map I use. I also get similar results using the following map:
$$f(x,y)=(\sin(ay)-\cos(bx),\sin(cx)-\cos(dy))$$
The solutions with negative sum seem more likely to contain sparse, periodic-looking attractors, whereas the solutions with positive sum appear more chaotic.
Edit: Two examples: In the quadratic map, for coefficients [0.83, -0.8, -0.65, -0.37, -1.29, 0.7, -0.47, -0.47, 1.42, 0.92, 0.84, 0.39], both exponents are positive, with $\lambda_1=0.154$ and $\lambda_2=0.077$. On the other hand, for coefficients [0.57, -1.91, 0.94, -0.19, 1.92, 0.51, 0.15, -1.69, 1.69, -0.06, 0.64, 0.99], we find the exponents have opposite sign: $\lambda_1=0.173$ and $\lambda_2=-0.128$. Both of these spectra were checked with my code as well as with ChaosTools in Julia. During one runthrough of the notebook I found 26 cases where $\lambda_1+\lambda_2>0$, in which 10 cases had $\lambda_2>0$ and 16 cases had $\lambda_2<0$.

What is the sign of $\lambda_2$ in both cases? It may be that the "stretching" of the state space is outweighing the "squeezing" if $\lambda_2<0$, or if both are positive you may just have a system that is sensitive to initial conditions. In either case, if you cannot compute the Kaplan-Yorke dimension, there are other options. Check out the section on information dimension in Eckmann & Ruelle 1985

@whpowell96 Well, when $\lambda_1+\lambda_2<0$ it follows that $\lambda_2<0$, since I only kept solutions whose maximal exponent is positive, and I chose $\lambda_1$ to be the maximal exponent. When $\lambda_1+\lambda_2>0$, either $\lambda_2\geq0$ or $\lambda_2<0$ (I've found solutions for both cases). I updated my answer to include a couple examples. And I will look at the source you referenced, thanks.
